# PrimaryKeyRelatedField or Nested Relationships in Django REST

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My issue is I want to get this:

**output**

```
"counter": 1,
"reference": {
   "ref": "a",
   "name": "apple",
   "description": "a fruit"
        },
"stock": 10,
```

**serializers.py with PrimaryKeyRelatedField**

```
class StockSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    counter = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Counter.objects.all())
    reference = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Reference.objects.all())
    
    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        fields = ['counter', 'reference', 'stock']
```

**serializers.py with Nested Relationships**

```
class ReferenceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Reference
        fields = ['ref', 'name', 'description']

class StockSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    counter = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Counter.objects.all())
    reference = ReferenceSerializer()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        depth = 2
        fields = ['counter', 'reference', 'stock']
```

If I use PrimaryKeyRelatedField I have only the id but if I use Nested Relationships I have to fill all fields but it already exists I want to select among a list

Answer (score 3):

You can have two fields - one read_only and the other write only, like this:

```
class StockSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    counter = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Counter.objects.all())
    reference = ReferenceSerializer(read_only=True)
    reference_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Reference.objects.all(), write_only=True)
```

When the API sends data it shows `reference` and when it receives input, it gets `reference_id`

Comment: Thanks! Didnt realise you could have both readable and writable seralizer fields in one class